# How do create a meeting bot for google meets that records meeting?

Tags: python-3.x, bots, google-meet

Hey everyone I am trying to create a meeting bot for Google meet.  I am building this as a part of a product I am creating.  I am wondering how meeting bots are entering meetings, recording them, and then storing them for the user to use.

What is the scalable approach since I need to roll this out to multiple users?  This is similar to Otter.ai, Firelies.ai, and etc.

**My idea to get this working is to automate a browser and have a "service account", just another user account, join the meeting and begin recording.  Then request the recording from the google meet api and store it in my database and reference the attendees.**

Since I would be *automating a browser*, this doesn't sound like a good idea and hacky.  Is there a more standard way to do this?  I find it hard to believe every major company doing this is automating browsers with selenium.

Comment: There is no API / SDK to develop Google Meet bots but there is a preview of the SDK Live Sharing.